# React updating component when params change with old state

Tags: reactjs

i'm rendering some router links with params that contain the the same url but different id params. The router view updates but the state is always behind 1.

here's my Router setup:

```
               <Router>
                <div>
                    <h1>HEY THERE</h1>
                    <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
                    <Link to={'/detail/13721'}>Show Number 1 </Link>
                    <Link to={'/detail/1228'}>Show Number 2</Link>
                </div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
                    <Route path="/detail/:id" component={DetailPage} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
```

Here's my detail page setup:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
class DetailPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={
            showid: '30318',
            showurl: 'http://localhost/podcast/podcastsbyid/?id=',
            shows: []
        }
    }
    render() { 
        return ( <div>
            <h1>Detail Page</h1><p>{this.state.showid}</p>
            {this.state.shows.map((show, i) => {
                return <div key={i}>{show.title}</div>
            })}
        </div>
         )
    }
    getShow(){
        fetch(this.state.showurl + this.state.showid).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            this.setState({shows: []})
            this.setState({shows: this.state.shows.concat(data.items)})
        })
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        if(this.state.showid == newProps.match.params.id){
            console.log('they are the same')      
        }
        else{
            console.log('they are different')
            this.setState({showid: newProps.match.params.id})
            this.getShow()
        }
    }
}
 
export default DetailPage;
```

any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I don't really understand your problem... URL is not updating?

Comment: it updates the component but it's always on the last state.  not the one that set with the new param on the other link.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] like a codesandbox?

Comment: ok.   when you click a link it updates the state it renders the show.id fine.  when it comes time to fetch the data, and render it, it's always a state behind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be state update being asynchronous. Try updating the code as shown below:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
    if(this.state.showid == newProps.match.params.id){
        console.log('they are the same')      
    }
    else{
        console.log('they are different')
        this.setState({showid: newProps.match.params.id}, this.getShow)
        // use it as callback ------------------------------^
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work.

Here's my example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-lehmann-s9i67?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @JodyChristian looks like there was a small typo: `this.getTodos())` vs `this.getTodos)` https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-bell-rfs7b?file=/src/DetailPage.js

Comment: Sorry I got that example up pretty quick